# Webpack generates chunk files I do not understand

Tags: webpack

After compiling, I see weird files being generated, such as:

- 6.2ca126ea.js

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[6,7,8,9],{1224:function(n,o){},1225:function(n,o){},1226:function(n,o){},1233:function(n,o){},1234:function(n,o){},239:function(n,o){}}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=6.2ca126ea.js.map
```

- 7.e1babd65.js.map

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[7,8],{1224:function(n,o){},1225:function(n,o){},1226:function(n,o){},1233:function(n,o){},1234:function(n,o){}}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=7.e1babd65.js.map
```

- 8.661ee447.js.map

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[8,7],{1224:function(n,o){},1225:function(n,o){},1226:function(n,o){},1233:function(n,o){},1234:function(n,o){}}]);
//# sourceMappingURL=8.661ee447.js.map
```

Looked over every option of optimization in webpack configuration

My optimization conf is:

```
const optimizationConf = {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      'project-core': {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]project-core[\\/]/,
        name: 'project-core',
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      },
      'project-tools': {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]project-tools[\\/]/,
        name: 'project-tools',
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      },
      '3rdparty': {
        test: /[\\/]src[\\/]3rdparty[\\/]/,
        name: '3rdparty',
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      },
      vendors: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendors',
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And there are so many files like these.
They usually measure in bytes (plus the source map associated to each file)

How can I avoid these files being generated or even put them in a single file ?

Comment: Have you read the doc on chunk splitting ? It's very useful when you frequently update your website https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: @Seblor Of course I have read it, do you think I missed something related to those glue files ? Do you know more ?